# Adding admin for specific users

Tags: plugin-development, admin, user-roles

I was developing a website and I ran into this issue where I need to provide an "admin" account that can monitor registered user activity on my site. Now I don't want one "admin" to view users that are assigned to a different "admin". Basically an additional "admin" role with privileges above that of a user and less than that of a site administrator providing capabilities to view all user content such as profiles and messages and tomodify it but unable to change the layout of the website. 
Is there already some software/snippet I can use or do I have to code it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use add_role function :

```
  add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities );
```

Just set your custom values as you wish :

```
add_role('basic_contributor', 'Basic Contributor', array(
    'read' => true, // True allows that capability
    'edit_posts' => true,
    'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
));
```

Plugin : 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/